# How to correctly propagate session id to other php pages?

Tags: php, session

I tried to find a lot on internet, but there is no understandable way of propagating session IDs to other php pages. How to do that?

Comment: You really couldn't find anything on the Internet? How about the PHP manual pages  on [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Look especially at the section on [Passing the session ID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)

Answer (score 3):

The session variables are global variables and are available in all the PHP pages

There must be `session_start()` in all the pages.

Comment: The Q was, how the ID of a particular session is passed between the disjoint requests to PHP pages. This has to be already done when invoking `session_start()`. I'm not going to down vote this, but it's only half the way. Usually, the session ID is stored in a cookie on the client (`PHPSESSION`). All `session_...` functions will read/set this cookie in order to identify and separate the particular session.

Comment: @AxelAmthor, this can also be the answer.